# How to solve this using probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory

In 7 story building 3 persons got on an empty elevator on the first floor. Each of them can get out at any floor independent of each others starting from the 2nd floor. What is the probability that each of them getting out at different floor?

Comment: Presumably, you mean at any floor with equal probability - that is, person A gets out at floor $k$ with probability $1/6$ for $k=2,3,\dots,7$.

Comment: You are tossing $3$ (fair) dice, and want the probability the results are all different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label the people $A, B,C$.

Person $A$ has 6 floors she can get off at.

Person $B$ has only 5 floors she can get off at (this is because person $B$ cannot get off on the same floor as person $A$).

Person $C$ then has $4$ floors she can get off at (since she can not get off at the same floor as either person $A$ or $B$).

Thus, there are $4\cdot 5\cdot 6=120$ ways these three people can get off at different floors. Now, assuming there were no constraints on which floors the people excited, each person would have a total of 6 floors to choose to get off at, for a combined total of $6^{3}=216$ ways the people could have chosen to get off.

Therefore, the desired probability is $\frac{120}{216}=\frac{5}{9}$.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First person can get out at 6 different floors the second can only chose the 5 others and the last one can only chose 4. The total number of possibilities are $6^3$ so the answer should be.

$\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{6^3}=\frac{5}{9}=0.55...$